# autoconf configure results in C std lib header related compile errors

Tags: c, linux, makefile, autoconf, automake

I am attempting to build a project that comes with an automake/autoconf build system.  This is a well-used project, so I'm skeptical about a problem with the configure scripts, makefiles, or code as I received them.  It is likely some kind of environment, path, flag, etc problem - something on my end with simply running the right commands with the right parameters.

The configuration step seems to complete in a satisfactory way.  When I run make, I'm shown a set of errors primarily of these types:

```
error: ‘TRUE’ undeclared here (not in a function)
error: ‘struct work’ has no member named ‘version’
error: expected ‘)’ before ‘PRIu64’
```

Let's focus on the last one, which I have spent time researching - and I suspect all the errors are related to missing definitions.  Apparently the print-friendly extended definitions from the C standard library header file **inttypes.h** is not being found.  However, in the configure step everything is claimed to be in order:

```
configure:4930: checking for inttypes.h
configure:4930: /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:4930: $? = 0
configure:4930: result: yes
```

All the INTTYPES flags are set correctly if I look in confdefs.h, config.h, config.log Output Variables, etc:

```
HAVE_INTTYPES_H='1'
#define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
```

The problem is the same whether doing a native build, or cross-compiling (for arm-linux-gnueabihf, aka armhf).

The source .c file in question does have config.h included as you'd expect, which by my understanding via the m4 macros mechanic should be adding an

```
#include <inttypes.h>
```

line.  Yes, as you may be inclined to ask, if I enter this line myself into the .c file it appears to work and the PRIu64 errors go away.

I'm left with wondering how to debug this type of problem - **essentially, everything I am aware of tells me I've done the configure properly, but I'm left with a bogus make process**.  Aside from trying every ./configure tweak and trick I can find, I've started looking at the auto-generated Makefile.in itself, but nothing so far.  Also looking into how I can get the C pre-processor to tell me which header files it's actually inserting.

EDIT:  I've confirmed that the -DHAVE_CONFIG_H mechanic looks good through configure, config.log, Makefile, etc.

Comment: My problem here was the assumption that the code I received was correct, which it should have been given it's development history.  Turns out the problem IS in the code and not with the autotools configuration.  Also, I never came across clear autotools documentation about the #include directives, so I believed it generated them automatically - I had mistakenly thought that was a key feature of the tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

autoconf does not automatically produce `#include` directives.  You need to do that on your own based on the `HAVE_*` macros.  So you'll have to add something like this:

```
#ifdef HAVE_INTTYPES_H
# include <inttypes.h>
#endif
```

If these lines show up in `confdefs.h`, a temporary header file used by `configure` scripts, this does excuse your application from performing these `#include`s.  If `configure` writes them to `confdefs.h`, this is solely for the benefit of other `configure` tests, and not for application use.

Comment: The preliminary confdefs.h section of config.log shows me those lines, so I have to think that is set up correctly.  Further down under Output Variables, we have the confdefs.h section showing `#define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. `confdefs.h` is a temporary header used by the configure checks.

Comment: I think I follow.  I see these lines in the given .c source for example:  ````#ifdef HAVE_CURSES
#include <curses.h>
#endif```` so they are taking advantage of the ````#define HAVE_CURSES 1```` line which is in config.h.  I would do the same for HAVE_INTTYPES_H, which is NOT present in the source file.  Does  work; I'm just not understanding how that critical piece was missing given the history and use of this package.  I was expecting I received this code from the repo able to be built; now I am seeing that's not the case, thus a new mystery to solve.  Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

First, run `make -n` for the target that failed. This is probably some `.o` file; you may need some tweaking to get its path correctly.

Now you have the command used to compile your file. If you don't find the problem by meditating on this command, try to run it, adding the `-E` to force preprocessor output text instead of invoking the compiler.

Note that now the `.o` file will be text, and you must rebuild it without `-E` later.

You may find some [preprocessor flags](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.1/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) useful to get more details: **-dM** or **-dD**, or others.

Comment: Great suggestion.  Having a bit of trouble doing this inside the configure work flow, however.  For example, if I do `CFLAGS="-E" ./configure` then I get `checking whether the C compiler works... no` and `configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables` which is understandable because the compiler is not invoked after the CPP... but then how do I read the CPP output?

Comment: `make -n` output looks good, key is the `HAVE_CONFIG_H` as seen here: `echo "  CC      " app-app.o;/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -lpthread -fno-strict-aliasing -I./compat/jansson-2.6/src -I./compat/jansson-2.6/src -I./compat/libusb-1.0/libusb -I./compat/libusb-1.0/libusb -I./lib -I./lib    -g -O2 -MT app-app.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/app-app.Tpo -c -o app-app.o (etc,etc)` ... given that it works fine with the include inserted manually, I don't think there's anything wrong with the include paths.

Comment: No, you don't feed `-E` to ./configure. You copy the output of `make -n` and paste it into command line. If it fails the same way as before, you can add `-E` to figure out why **HAVE_CONFIG_H** doesn't have the expected effect.

Comment: This is really good make knowledge, I applaud you sir.  Turns out the problem is that the code was NOT in good shape coming out of the repo as it should have been and I believed it was.  My ignorance of the autotools meant I didn't see the obvious.